# How to add font styling tags to text in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I am creating an application in which i need to add font styling tags to text like this.

```
bold        :<b>bold</b>
italic      :<i>italic</i>
underline   :<u>underline</u>
font colour :<font color="#ff0000"> sfsg </font>
font size   :<font size="50.5"> asdasd </font>
font style  :<font face="consolas">Aorion</font>
```

The HTMLEditor in javafx contains many extra buttons which i dont need. How can i remove those extra buttons or what can be an alternative implementation?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but I guess you want to style separated segments of a `TextArea`, don't you?

Comment: Probably the easiest solution is to use a `WebView` with your own HTML content.

Comment: @adxl the user will select the text and click the button for bold, italic etc to manipulate font style. But other options in javafx html editor are useless and i dont want to show it to the user

Comment: @Slaw can you please give coding example??

Comment: Are you looking for a [Rich Text Editor](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX)?